# Supply specific implementation to an interface dependency only for a specific component

Tags: castle-windsor

I implemented Decorator pattern on BooCustom

```
public class BooDefault : IBoo{}
public class BooCustom : IBoo
{
    public BooCustom(IBoo boo)
    {
    }
}
```

than I have a component Foo

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(IBoo boo)
    {
    }
}
```

that depends on IBoo and only for this one I need BooCustom be the implementation for IBoo.

Any components depending on IBoo but Foo  will use BooDefault including BooCustom.

Only Foo needs to have his IBoo dependency resolved by BooCustom instead of BooDefault.

How can I accomplish this resolution with windsor?

```
Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>()
    .Supply_BooCustom_as_Concrete_for_IBoo - Foo Dependency
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Handler Selectors](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Handler-Selectors.ashx). You should be able to create one that checks if the type requesting an IBoo is Foo.  If so, it can return a specific component (in this case, the BooCustom).

Comment: I cannot figure out how to write if condition to solve my need.
public class MyHandlerSelector : IHandlerSelector
{
public bool HasOpinionAbout(string key, Type service)
{
return service == typeof(IBoo);
}

public IHandler SelectHandler(string key, Type service, IHandler[] handlers)
{
if(service.IsDependecyFor<Foo>())
 return handlers.Where(x => x.ComponentModel
  .Implementation == typeof(BooCustom)).First();

return handlers.Where(x => x.ComponentModel
 .Implementation == typeof(BooDefault)).First();
}
}

Comment: Can you show the code where you register all of these components?

Comment: Program.Container.Register
(
 Component.For<IBoo>().ImplementedBy<BooDefault>(),
 Component.For<MyBoo>(),
 Component.For<BooCustom>(),
 Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>(),
 Component.For<MyHandlerSelector>()
);
Program.Container.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(new MyHandlerSelector());

Comment: What does MyBoo look like?  And what is "IsDependencyFor<T>" -- is that a custom extension method for Type?

Comment: Forget about MyBoo, just an additional test to have IBoo resolved with default concrete as BooDefault.
"IsDependencyFor<T>" is just meta-code to explain what i'd like to accomplish. In other word in SelectHandler I need to distiguish which handlers has to be selected as concrete for IBoo according to cmp/interface is requesting IBoo: in SelectHandler I need to know who is requesting IBoo interface so I can serve different concrete for it

Comment: Maybe I'm over-complicating this.  Why can't Foo have a dependency on BooCustom -- instead of IBoo?  I mean, that's really what you want in there anyway.  It would negate the need for the Handler Selector as well.

Comment: You are right, but in that case Foo won't depend anymore on an interface(IBoo) but on a concrete(BooCustom) instead

Comment: You can still type it as an IBoo internally (inside Foo).  But the ctor argument can be BooCustom.